# Toggle button animation not working in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm following a YouTube tutorial on creating animated toggle button. here is the code but it's not working. I guess there is a problem with `@property` but I'm not sure.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ToggleButton(QCheckBox):
    def __init__(self, 
        width = 70, 
        bgColor = '#777', 
        circleColor = '#DDD', 
        activeColor = '#00BCff', 
        animationCurve = QEasingCurve.OutBounce
    ):
        QCheckBox.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(width, 40)
        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

        self._bg_color = bgColor
        self._circle_color = circleColor
        self._active_color = activeColor
        self._circle_position = 3
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"circle_position")
        self.animation.setEasingCurve(animationCurve)
        self.animation.setDirection(500)
        self.stateChanged.connect(self.start_transition)

    @property
    def circle_position(self):
        return self._circle_position

    @circle_position.setter
    def circle_position(self, pos):
        self._circle_position = pos
        self.update()

    def start_transition(self, value):
        print(self.isChecked())
        self.animation.stop()
        if value:
            self.animation.setEndValue(self.width() - 26)
        else:
            self.animation.setEndValue(3)

        self.animation.start()

    def hitButton(self, pos: QPoint):
        return self.contentsRect().contains(pos)


    def paintEvent(self, e):
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        p.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        rect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

        if not self.isChecked():
            p.setBrush(QColor(self._bg_color))
            p.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, rect.width(), self.height(), self.height() / 2, self.height() / 2)

            p.setBrush(QColor(self._circle_color))
            p.drawEllipse(self._circle_position, 3, 32, 32)
        
        else:
            p.setBrush(QColor(self._active_color))
            p.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, rect.width(), self.height(), self.height() / 2, self.height() / 2)

            p.setBrush(QColor(self._circle_color))
            p.drawEllipse(self._circle_position, 3, 32, 32)

        p.end()


class window(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self, parent = None):
      super(window, self).__init__(parent)
      self.resize(500,500)
      self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5")
      self.toggleBtn = ToggleButton()
      self.container = QFrame()
      self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
      self.layout.addWidget(self.toggleBtn, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.AlignCenter)
      self.container.setLayout(self.layout)
      self.setCentralWidget(self.container)


def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = window()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the code you will get the following warning:

```
QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property circle_position of your QObject
```

QPropertyAnimation only applies to Qt Properties, not python properties so it fails and we get that warning. In addition there are other errors in the handling of the transition, there is also a typo since instead of using duration direction is used.

```py
class ToggleButton(QCheckBox):
    def __init__(
        self,
        width=70,
        bgColor="#777",
        circleColor="#DDD",
        activeColor="#00BCff",
        animationCurve=QEasingCurve.OutBounce,
    ):
        QCheckBox.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(width, 40)
        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

        self._bg_color = bgColor
        self._circle_color = circleColor
        self._active_color = activeColor
        self._circle_position = 3
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"circle_position")

        self.animation.setEasingCurve(animationCurve)
        self.animation.setDuration(500)
        self.stateChanged.connect(self.start_transition)

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def circle_position(self):
        return self._circle_position

    @circle_position.setter
    def circle_position(self, pos):
        self._circle_position = pos
        self.update()

    def start_transition(self, value):
        self.animation.setStartValue(self.circle_position)
        if value:
            self.animation.setEndValue(self.width() - 35)
        else:
            self.animation.setEndValue(3)
        self.animation.start()

    def hitButton(self, pos: QPoint):
        return self.contentsRect().contains(pos)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        p.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        rect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

        if not self.isChecked():
            p.setBrush(QColor(self._bg_color))
            p.drawRoundedRect(
                0, 0, rect.width(), self.height(), self.height() / 2, self.height() / 2
            )

            p.setBrush(QColor(self._circle_color))
            p.drawEllipse(self._circle_position, 3, 32, 32)
        else:
            p.setBrush(QColor(self._active_color))
            p.drawRoundedRect(
                0, 0, rect.width(), self.height(), self.height() / 2, self.height() / 2
            )

            p.setBrush(QColor(self._circle_color))
            p.drawEllipse(self._circle_position, 3, 32, 32)
```